# How to get the date from specific string format using tome zone in iphone

Tags: iphone, nsdate

hello all I have the date in string format "2009-07-06T02:05:11.000+10:00" which i have taken from xml.. Now i need to convert that into date format and use it.How could I do this 
Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

See the doc for [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Roughly as follows:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"DATE FORMAT HERE !!!"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"DATE TEXT STRING"];
```